# How does Angular know what the types of a constructor are?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been trying to replicate the way Angular interprets the constructor on an injectable service.

```
function Injectable() {
  return function<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(con: T) {
    return class extends con {
      static __constructorClasses: any[] = [];

      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args);
        Foo.__constructorClasses = ???;
      }
    };
  };
}
```

How can I return a list of classes into the `Foo.__constructorClasses`

```
class Bar {
  public hello = 'world';
}

@Injectable()
class Foo {
  constructor(private bar: Bar) {}
}

// I expect: Foo.__constructorClasses = [Bar]
const bar = new Foo.__constructorClasses[0]();
console.log(bar.hello) // 'world'
```

Am I going about this in the wrong way?  My goal is to know (after converting to es2015+) what each of the classes are in the constructor.  So that I either have the class itself `[Bar]` or a string representing the class `'Bar'`.  The string is also fine because I can use it to pull the `Bar` instance from a Proxy.

Comment: > `replicate the way Angular interprets the constructor on an injectable service`, Angular doesn't do it like that. TypeScript emits metadata about classes and Angular accesses it via `reflect-metadata` (JIT). In the AOT mode - Angular collects metadata before runtime and stores it in the `ngInjectableDef` static property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Utilizing:**

- typescript: 3.5.3
- reflect-metadata: 0.1.13

**Command to run:**

`tsc foo.ts --emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators && node foo.js`

**foo.ts:**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

type Constructor<T> = { new (...args: any[]): T };

function Injectable() {
  return function _Injectable<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
    return class __Injectable extends Base {
      classes: any[] = Reflect.getMetadata(
        'design:paramtypes',
        __Injectable.prototype.constructor
      );

      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args);
      }
    }
  };
}

class Bar {
  label: string;

  constructor() {
    this.label = 'BarClass';
  }
}

@Injectable()
class Foo {
  constructor(private bar: Bar) {}
}

const bar = new Bar();
const foo = new Foo(bar);

//@ts-ignore // ts doesn't strictly know that classes exists on Foo
console.log(foo.classes); // [ [Function: Bar] ]
//@ts-ignore // ts doesn't strictly know that classes exists on Foo
console.log(new foo.classes[0]().label); // 'BarClass'
```

**Most of the information was available here**: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html however I thought this quick example would more simply demonstrate how Typescript can emit the classes passed to a classes constructor.

**Further Reading:**

https://codeburst.io/decorate-your-code-with-typescript-decorators-5be4a4ffecb4
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html
https://blog.wizardsoftheweb.pro/typescript-decorators-reflection/